# Remote foriegn key on SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am building a database on SQL Server 2014. I have a users table and a profiles table and I need to have a relationship with both these tables. I am relating the userid (primary key on user table) to the profiles table (userid there as foreign key). This is just an example to consider.

What I need to know is, what if the profiles table is on another server instance? Is there a way with which I can link both? The reason is that I don't want to overload the sql server with too many tables and data...
Thanks,
Sarin Gopalan

Answer (score 1):

It is not at all possible to create foreign key relations between databases - let alone between server instances.

You might be able to create a trigger on the Profiles table, that checks if a userid exists in the User table in the other database, but I fear the performance of this approach will be very bad.

A much better solution would be to replicate one table to the other database, and then create the foreign key relations in a normal way. How you replicate the table (SSIS, CDC, triggers, etc.) is up to you.

Comment: Thanks! and Yes, replicating seems like a good idea. Just wondering about how the delete and update operations on the main table would affect the other db tables...

Comment: If you want to, you can enable cascading updates/deletes when defining your foreign key relations. This way, records in foreign tables are automatically deleted/updated when something happens in the primary table. The default is that cascades are disabled - this causes an error when you attempt to delete a record from a primary table when there is a foreign record referencing it. But once again - this only works when tables are in the same database, so you will still need to handle the replication of one of the tables between the databases somehow.

Comment: Can I not make use of triggers for that?

Comment: Sure, but normally it's much easier just to enable cascades (it's a simple setting on the foreign key - much easier than to write a trigger).